# Plugging in computer to internet switch makes nothing work

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ethernet

Hey guys, so I came across a very odd problem, I recently bought a refurbished computer and put Ubuntu 16 onto it. However whenever I connect this computer to my ethernet-switch, after about 10-20 sec everything connected to the switch will no longer connect to the internet or LAN. I have no idea why this happening and any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @Zac67 sorry I wasn't sure if it could be fixed with programming, for example if it was possible that this computer was destroying the spanning tree, then maybe some static rules could be programmed to fix it

Comment: What is the network config like? Is it overlapping with the default gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I fixed the problem, for some reason when I take out my gpu the problem stops, although I have no idea how the gpu would affect my internet connection.